# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':client:shadowJar'

Tags: kotlin, gradle, sgx, enclave, conclave

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':client:shadowJar'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':client:runtimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.r3.conclave:conclave-client:1.1.

Tried to run event manager conclave and received error message

https://github.com/r3conclave/conclave-samples

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the slow response.    Quick question: can you post the contents of your `gradle.properties` file please? And can you also confirm if any other commands (eg `gradlew host:run`) work?   We think it might be that your `conclaveRepo` setting in the properties file is wrong but this will help us check.

Comment: hi there , apologies, i have already resolved the issue , thank you for the response .

Comment: No worries!  Do you recall what the solution was? Would be good to capture it here if so in case anybody else hits it in the future?